# identification of polygons sides

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am studying algebraic topology and I am having a really hard time in trying to figure out this particular argument. While I somehow manage to understand the proofs that use retraction by deformation, or Van Kampen, I cannot understand those problems involving the identification of sides of a polygon. Could someone please explain how all of this work? I think I get what you do with a thorus (that famous square where you identify opposite edges), but when you have to deal with something more complicated like a double-thorus or even triple, I really can't see it. I mean, for instance the teacher told us that a double thorus can be seen by using an octagon (I think?) and identifying its edges in some way, but I can't see the logic behind it. And this is even worse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus-three_surface

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: This is explained very nicely in Massey's Algebraic Topology: An Introduction.

Comment: If you understand how to obtain the fundamental polygon of a torus and projective plane, then it is easy to obtain the fundamental polygons of all the higher genus surfaces through connected sums.

Comment: Is a thorus connectable to a torus ?

Comment: @AlexProvost could you please try to explain, even briefly? We have not seen connected sums, so I don't get what you are trying to suggest

Comment: I wouldn't be able to explain it better than the book itself, so have a look at it. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/l0EVNKO.png) is the picture to have in mind, straight from the book. The idea is that to obtain a higher genus surface, you take two lower genus surfaces, cut out a disk from each, and glue them together across the resulting boundary circles. This is the so-called "connected sum" operation.